# Maintain session when calling a REST service from Java

Tags: java, rest, post, get

I am trying to call a web services which requires certain authorization(Login) from user.
Is it possible to maintain a session for that i can call those web services in java console base application.

for example:-
I have one rest API in which I can get the investor's investment by passing the investor id. To get the investment details by that particular investor user has to login(that is also another web service(i have create a api for login which i am calling to authorize the user)).
Can we pass header along with the get request if we can't maintain a session for that?

Please tell me. if I am not clear please comment below.
Thank You.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are writing a Java application and you want it to communicate with some Rest service? Please add some code you've written to call the service.

Comment: yes i have written java application which communicate with REST services.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a vague problem, I will try to give some pointers about a 'generic' solution. Your REST service can return an object linked with the credentials of the user. It's what's called a 'cookie'. Then, at each call, you just have to resend the cookie, and you have the credentials...

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/GetSetCookie.htm

Comment: is it possible to create cookies in java standalone application? if possible then my problem is solved.

Comment: You can get the cookies and save them manually to a file or keep it in memory.... Check google or maybe SO to find how to do it.... If you can with 'curl', you can do it in a java app.

Comment: #JFPicard can you pls provide me some link or any example? thnx